# Why can't I connect to Google Talk in agsXMPP?

Tags: mono, xmpp, agsxmpp

I'm trying to get started using [agsXMPP](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk.html), but I'm having some problems. I'm trying to run this code:

```
using System;
using agsXMPP;

namespace TestAgs
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            XmppClientConnection connection = new XmppClientConnection ();
            connection.OnLogin += delegate {
                Console.WriteLine ("logged in");
            };
            connection.Server = "gmail.com";
            connection.ConnectServer = "talk.google.com";
            connection.Username = "my username"; // I tried both with and without '@gmail.com'
            connection.Password = "my password";
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to run it, nothing happens. It runs and completes without any errors, but "logged in" never gets printed to the console. What am I doing wrong?

If it makes a difference, I'm using Mono 2.4 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless connection.Open () blocks, which I doubt, the issue is that your program hits the end of main, and therefore it is done running and ends.

How you want to keep it from exiting depends on what you are trying to do, but one way would be a ManualResetEvent:

```
var mre = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent (false);
mre.WaitOne ();
```

Of course, now you may have the opposite problem, there is no way for your app to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I think issue is port number. You did not supply 5222 or 5223 in the connection.

Comment: Thanks Pujan, with jpobst's tip, it works with or without the port number.

Comment: port number is set by default in Jabber References.

Answer (score 1):

just add Console.ReadLine(); after the line  'connection.Open();'

Answer (score 0):

```
// connection.Server = "gmail.com";
connection.ConnectServer = "talk3.l.google.com"; OR
connection.ConnectServer = "talk2.l.google.com";
connection.Username = "my username"; // I tried both with and without '@gmail.com'
connection.Password = "my password";
connection.Open();
```

`talk3.l.google` worked fine for me.